# AWS Load Balancer Path Based Routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I am running a microservice application off of AWS ECS. Each microservice currently has its own Load balancer.

There is one main public facing service which the rest of the services communicate with via gateways. Having each service have its own ELB is currently too expensive, is there some way to have only 1 ELB for the public facing service that will route to the other services based off of path. Is this possible without actually having the other service names in the URL. Could a reverse proxy work?

I know this is a broad question but any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Inside your EC2 panel go to `loadbalancers` section, choose a loadbalancer and then in `listeners` tab, there is a button named `view/edit rules`, there you set conditions to use a single loadbalancer for different clusters/instances of your app. note that for each container you need a `target group` defined.

You can config loadbalancer to route based on:

1. `Http Headers`
2. `Path` i.e: [www.example.com/a](http://www.example.com/a) or [www.example.com/b](http://www.example.com/b)
3. `Host Header(hostname)`
4. `Query strings`
5. or even `source Ip`.

That's it! cheers.

Comment: could you please provide an example config for two different host names? @hossein-heydari

Comment: in `view/edit` rules explained above, you can set `if conditions`, first setup your hostnames and DNS config and all it needs on `route 53` or `cloudfront` or any other thing you're doing, then simply add your hostnames here, if `aa.com` route to `target group A` if `bb.com` route to `target group B`